# Laravel, Vue component template not show?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Sorry, my English is so bad!

File: app.js

```
window.auth_id = 0;
Vue.component('block-header-user-control', require('./HeaderComponent.vue'));
new Vue({
    el: '#application'
});
```

File HeaderComponent.vue

```
<template lang="html">
    <header-guest v-if="!auth"></header-guest>
    <header-auth v-else></header-auth>
</template>

<script>

    import HeaderGuest from './HeaderUserGuest.vue';
    import HeaderAuth from './HeaderUserAuth.vue';

    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                auth: window.auth_id
            }
        },
        components: {
            'header-guest': HeaderGuest,
            'header-auth': HeaderAuth,
        },
        methods: {},
    }
</script>
```

File: HeaderUserGuest.vue

```
<script>
    export default {
        template: '#header-user-auth', // Not working,
        // template: `<div>cascaaSA</div>`, // working
        data() {
            return {}
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Created Guest');
        },
    }
</script>
```

File: HeaderUserAuth.vue

```
<script>
    export default {
        template: '#header-user-auth',
        name: 'header-auth',
        data() {
            return {}
        },
        created() {
            console.log('Created Auth');
        },
    }
</script>
```

File: index.blade.php

```
<div id="application">
    <script type="text/x-template" id="header-user-guest">
       Guest
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-template" id="header-user-auth">
       Logged
    </script>
    <block-header-user-control></block-header-user-control> 
</div>
```

"Created Guest" is displayed in browser console, but the "block-header-user-control" menu does not display "Guest".

Please help me. SPECIAL THANKS!!

====================

Thank all! It worked with html. Text not working

```
<div id="application">
    <script type="text/x-template" id="header-user-guest">
       <div>Guest</div>
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-template" id="header-user-auth">
       <div>Logged</div>
    </script>
    <block-header-user-control></block-header-user-control> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to move your templates outside of the scope of the application - move them below `#application`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I moved it outside <div id="application"></div> But it still does not work